# Combining Multiple records with the same id in 1 row for display purposes from 1 table

Tags: sql, row

Records form Purchases file

```
ID  Date        Qty Price Volume
1   01/04/2016 200 R34.00 11
1   01/05/2016 175 R15.00  2
1   01/06/2016 340 R75.00  14
1   01/07/2016 150 R150.00 23
```

**Desired results via SQL code**

```
ID   Description  April    May   June July (Strip month from date)
 1   Quantity:    200      175   340   150
     Price   :    R34.00   15.00 R75.00 R150.00
     Volume  :    11        2     14    23
 2  Repeat
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Comment: This type of operation should be done by the application.  One major hint is that the rows in each column have different types.